# If client terminates RESTful request, handle IOException explicitly

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs, ioexception

I have a custom client tool which makes a HTTP request to my RESTful server API.

The request can take ~1 minute (as files are uploaded in a multi part fashion, as part of the user's profile) and possibly the client process could be terminated by the user or the terminal window gets closed. Resulting in all files not being uploaded.

If the client tool is killed (terminating the connection), `java.io.IOException` is seen in the server logs but looks like the `Exception` is handled/consumed by the container (Using WAS Liberty Profile). When this happens I would like to do some additional processing server-side, to cleanup the incomplete profile.

I'm trying to use an `ExceptionMapper` to catch `IOException` but `toResponse()` is never called .. Am I missing something?

`MyApplication.java`:

```
package com.test.server;

import com.test.exceptions.IOExceptionMapper;
import com.test.server.Service;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public final Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MyService.class);
        classes.add(MyApplication.class);
        classes.add(IOExceptionMapper.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

`MyService.java`:

```
package com.test.server;

@WebService
@Path("/")
public class MyService {

    @POST
    @Path("/profile")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response createProfile(@javax.ws.rs.core.Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
        @javax.ws.rs.core.Context final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        // do things, duration is ~1 minute

        ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(Status.OK).entity("Created.");
        return rb.build();
    }
}
```

`IOExceptionMapper.java`:

```
package com.test.exceptions;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Singleton
public class IOExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<IOException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("toResponse IOExceptionMapper");
        return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

Snippet from `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <description>API</description>
    <display-name>RESTAPI</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RESTAPI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.server.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.exceptions</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Server logs:

```
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.io.IOException: Connection closed: Read failed.  Possible end of stream encountered.  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.PostParameterHelper 402" at ffdc_19.01.30_18.23.41.0.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.io.IOException: Connection closed: Read failed.  Possible end of stream encountered.  com.ibm.wsspi.http.ee7.HttpInputStreamEE7 129" at ffdc_19.01.30_18.23.41.1.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.io.IOException: SRVE0216E: post body contains less bytes than specified by content-length. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.PostParameterHelper 402" at ffdc_19.01.30_18.23.41.2.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.io.IOException: Connection closed: Read failed.  Possible end of stream encountered.  org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit 786" at ffdc_19.01.30_18.23.45.0.log
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.io.IOException: Connection closed: Read failed.  Possible end of stream encountered.  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.finish 875" at ffdc_19.01.30_18.23.45.1.log
```

Comment: It the exception even being thrown at the Jersey level? The ExceptionMapper will only handle exceptions thrown _within_ the Jersey application.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too when I said "but looks like the `Exception` is handled/consumed by the container (Using WAS Liberty Profile)" .. If it is being thrown outside the Jersey application, is it possible to handle this at a code level? Maybe some additional config needed too?